# Node.js Request error - ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Every now and then, as I'm requesting data from a github-issue, I get this error when firing my request-promise-function:

```
{ RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at new RequestError (/vagrant/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/vagrant/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/vagrant/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/vagrant/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/vagrant/node_modules/request/request.js:859:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:358:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1283:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
From previous event:
    at Request.plumbing.init (/vagrant/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:36:28)
    at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (/vagrant/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:41:27)
    at new Request (/vagrant/node_modules/request/request.js:129:8)
    at request (/vagrant/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)
    at module.exports (/vagrant/resources/GetIssuesData.js:25:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/vagrant/app.js:42:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at /vagrant/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: read ECONNRESET',
  cause: 
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1029:11)
       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:575:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' },
  error: 
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1029:11)
       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:575:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' },
  options: 
   { uri: 'https://api.github.com/repos/1dv023/jp222vq-examination-3/issues?access_token=TOKEN',
     headers: 
      { 'User-Agent': 'me',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
     simple: false,
     reconnect: true,
     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
     transform: undefined,
     resolveWithFullResponse: false,
     transform2xxOnly: false },
  response: undefined }
```

The request is fired every time a user requests a new page on the application, and is also fired when changes are made in the github-issue. The request feeds a socket-eventemitter with data. This is the request-function:

```
(function() {

    let rp = require("request-promise");

    module.exports = function(res, callback) {

        let options = {
            uri: "https://api.github.com/repos/" + res.issue,
            headers: {
                "User-Agent": "Me",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            simple: false,
            reconnect: true
        };

        rp(options)
            .then(function(body, err) {

                    try {
                        body = JSON.parse(body);

                        let context = {
                            issues: body.map(function(issue) {
                                return {
                                    title: issue.title,
                                    comments: issue.comments,
                                    uploaded: issue.created_at,
                                    updated: issue.updated_at,
                                    link: "/" + issue.number
                                };
                            }),
                        };
                        callback(context, null);
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw new Error(e)
                    }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                callback(null, err);
            });

    };
}());
```

I've been scratching my head for ages now, trying to understand why I get this error. Tried to read up on `ECONNRESET`, but didn't quite understand it. Can anybody please help?